# How to check the data in websocket?

Tags: html, websocket, crc

Am now using websocket in HTML5 to build my web app.

Because my previous work was based on TCP and I used CRC16 algorithm to wrap the content that will transfer to server side;

Construct message with CRC16 code below:

```
public static byte[] ConstructMessageWithCRC(string message)
{
    //Message with a | 
    var messageToConstruct = message + "|";

    //calculate CRC value
    var crcCode = CRC16.CalculateCrc16(messageToConstruct);
    var crcCodeShort = ushort.Parse(crcCode);

    //CRC high value
    var crcHigh = byte.Parse((crcCodeShort / 256).ToString());
    //CRC low value
    var crcLow = byte.Parse((crcCodeShort % 256).ToString());

    var messageBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(messageToConstruct);
    var messageLength = messageBytes.Length;

    var messageBytesWithCRC = new byte[messageLength + 2];
    Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, messageBytesWithCRC, 0, messageLength);

    //append crc value to the message
    messageBytesWithCRC[messageLength] = crcHigh;
    messageBytesWithCRC[messageLength + 1] = crcLow;

    return messageBytesWithCRC;
}
```

After server side received the data, it will calculate the content via CRC16 algorithm also to ensure that the data is correct.

Check CRC code below:

```
public static bool CheckMessageCRC(byte[] message, out string messageReceived)
{
    //message length that received
    var messageLength = message.Length;

    //message received without crc value
    var messageReceivedStrBytes = new byte[messageLength - 2];
    Array.Copy(message, 0, messageReceivedStrBytes, 0, messageLength - 2);

    //crc value received
    var messageReceivedCrcBytes = new byte[2];
    Array.Copy(message, messageLength - 2, messageReceivedCrcBytes, 0, 2);

    //get the received message with correct decoding
    var messageCalculatedString = Encoding.Default.GetString(messageReceivedStrBytes);
    messageReceived = messageCalculatedString;

    //get the received crc value 
    var currentCRC = byte.Parse(messageReceivedCrcBytes[0].ToString()) * 256 + byte.Parse(messageReceivedCrcBytes[1].ToString());

    //crc value recalculate
    var result = ushort.Parse(CRC16.CalculateCrc16(messageCalculatedString));
    //comparison
    if (currentCRC == result)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

From above code, you can see what I did.
But in some articles that using websocket: [Working with Websockets](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/working_with_websockets.html), it will use below code to handle the message directly:

```
    //When the server is sending data to this socket, this method is called
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {

        //Received data is a string; We parse it to a JSON object using jQuery
        //http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(evt.data);

        //Do something with the JSON object
    };


    //Creates an object that will be sent to the server
    var myObject = {
        Property: "Value",
        AnotherProperty: "AnotherValue"
    };

    //We need to stringify it through JSON before sending it to the server
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(myJsonObject));
```

It will directly send the data out without any check mechanism with the data. So if the data is intercepted by others and we won't know the data has been changed. Also, because of poor network, the data will arrival out of order, then below code won't work correctly, maybe we wanted data as ABC, but we got BCA:

```
 var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(evt.data);
```

So for evt.data, just wonder how should we check the data transfer complete, data order correct, data content correct and so on.

I have googled a lot and didn't see any info regarding this, just want use this question to declare the right way to transfer data via websocket, thx.

**EDIT:**
My friend send me this: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455, in [section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2)
I think the protocol seems do this work already. Need more of your discusses on it. thx

Comment: Just wonder, If anyone meets this scenario?

Comment: Wooooow, No one can share this scenario?

Comment: Ahhhha, Actually no one care about this!!